# 'Active' styling not being applied in conditional statement in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My file throws an error that says 'active' is not defined when I write this conditional statement for my className:

```
const NavigationItem = (props) => (
<li className='NavigationItem'>
<a href={props.link} 
className={props.active ? active : null}>{props.children}
</a>
</li>)
```

This is how I'm writing my component and passing active:

```
<NavigationItem link='/' active >Builder</NavigationItem>
```

I tried importing classes and doing classes.active in the className declaration and while that gets rid of the error the active is not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const NavigationItem = (props) => (
<li className='NavigationItem'>
<a href={props.link} 
className={props.active ? 'active' : null}>{props.children}
</a>
</li>)
```

you need turn active to string :D

Comment: haha you are welcome , some time when get stuck just take a coffe and look back
every thing will be okay :D